# AttributeError: 'MapDataset' object has no attribute 'gen_dataset' | tflite_model_maker | Creating a dataset for tflite recommender from a csv

Tags: python, dataset, tensorflow-lite

I'm attempting to train the tflite_model_maker recommendation on custom data but I'm running into issues with turning my CSV into a dataset that it'll accept. All of the examples I've found online are utilizing the MovieLens dataset which skips over this problem, and the steps I've found for just tflite don't seem to work here. This is the simplified version of what I'm stuck on currently, Any help would be appreciated.

Dataset sample:

```
   user_id  post_ids
0   228000    800472
1   228000    795240
2   228021    756878
3   228021    828332
4   228009    834848
```

My attempt to load the data:

```
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
data = pd.read_csv('./dataset.csv')
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(dict(data)).map(lambda x: {
    "user_id": int(x["user_id"]),
    "post_ids": int(x["post_ids"])
})
```

Attempt to train:

```
from tflite_model_maker import  recommendation
spec='recommendation_bow'
model_x = recommendation.create(
    dataset, spec, model_spec_options=None, model_dir=None,
    validation_data=None, batch_size=16, steps_per_epoch=10000, epochs=1,
    learning_rate=0.1, gradient_clip_norm=1.0, shuffle=True, do_train=True,
    max_history_length=10
)
```

Error:

```
INFO:tensorflow:Training recommendation model...
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-a1fef1fee081> in <module>()
      5     validation_data=None, batch_size=16, steps_per_epoch=10000, epochs=1,
      6     learning_rate=0.1, gradient_clip_norm=1.0, shuffle=True, do_train=True,
----> 7     max_history_length=10
      8 )

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_examples/lite/model_maker/core/task/recommendation.py in train(self, train_data, validation_data, batch_size, steps_per_epoch, epochs)
    101     batch_size = batch_size if batch_size else self.model_spec.batch_size
    102 
--> 103     train_ds = train_data.gen_dataset(
    104         batch_size, is_training=True, shuffle=self.shuffle)
    105     if validation_data:

AttributeError: 'MapDataset' object has no attribute 'gen_dataset'
```